# Routing in Custom Web Component Angular

Tags: angular, router, web-component

I tried create a custom web component by Angular

```
 ngDoBootstrap() {
const el = createCustomElement(ServicemainComponent, { injector:this.injector });
customElements.define('servicemain', el);
}
```

Then I build component to a javascript file and embed to Main project via Render 2

Every thing will be ok, but i want to apply child router in web component. Below is my router

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: 'services/apps/:id', component:ServicemainComponent,children:[
  { path: '', component: ServicehomeComponent},
  { path: 'create', component: ServicecreateComponent},
  { path: 'detail', component: ServicedetailComponent}
]},
{
  path: '**',
  redirectTo: '',
  pathMatch: 'full'
}
  ];
```

...

```
 imports: [
    BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
  ]
```

Then in ServicemainComponent, i try init router after it loaded

```
 export class ServicemainComponent implements OnInit {
 constructor(private router: Router) {
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("initialNavigation");
    this.router.initialNavigation();
  }
}
```

Routing work, but in my console, initialNavigation make a error : infinity loop

[image: Error image]

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a misunderstanding on how [InitialNavigation](https://angular.io/api/router/InitialNavigation#description) works. This method from the angular router is only to be used to set:

> an ExtraOptions object that configure when the router performs the
> initial navigation operation.

Your configuration makes angular router init every time the component is loaded... creating an infinite loop! You actually don't need to "start" or "init" the Angular router in your components. If you follow the [Angular router documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router), all you need to do is to include the **AppRoutingModule** inside your **app.module.ts**:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module'; // CLI imports AppRoutingModule
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule // CLI adds AppRoutingModule to the AppModule's imports array
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

It is then in this [app-routing.module.ts](https://angular.io/guide/router#nesting-routes) where you set your main and nested routes. Once you've done that, you can already access the router instance in `ServicemainComponent` like you are doing in the constructor: `constructor(private router: Router) {}`. However there is no need to initiate the instance of the router for navigating to the component, as the routes logic is set inside the **app-routing.module.ts**

Accessing the router instance in the component will allow you for example to programmatically navigate to another route, like in the example below:

```
this.router.navigate(['/heroes', { id: heroId }]);
```

Comment: Thank for your help! I tried : ngOnInit(): void { //console.log(window.location.hostname,window.location.pathname,window.location.origin); let link:string = window.location.pathname.slice(1,window.location.pathname.length)+'/home'; console.log(link); this.router.navigate([link]);   but result is the same